# Error when creating Kubernetes cluster on Azure - error: "code": "PropertyChangeNotAllowed"

Tags: azure, kubernetes

I am trying to create Kubernetes cluster on Microsoft Azure, but the operations fail and the following error message comes up (I use PUTTY on windows to generate the required ssh public key). Has anyone seen this before? Thanks!

"error": {
    "code": "PropertyChangeNotAllowed",
    "target": "linuxProfile.ssh.publicKeys.keyData",
    "message": "Changing property 'linuxProfile.ssh.publicKeys.keyData' is not allowed."

Comment: facing same issue. Any help

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when the cluster already exists.

Check the portal to make sure it doesn't already exist.